# C++ compiler error in count_if algorithm

Tags: c++, countif

I am running a simple STL algo to count the number of elements smaller than 50. This program generates the error "called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer". I've spent the night troubleshooting this, and looking for a similar question on stackoverflow without success, but at this hour I'm getting nowhere. I'd be grateful if someone could point out my error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool lessThan(double x)    //global function
{
    return (x < 50);
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> v1(5);    //create vector of 5 doubles
    for (auto i : v1) {    //for each element in v1...(auto used to determine type)
        v1[i] = rand() % 100;    //generate random numbers
        cout << v1[i] << endl;
        count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), lessThan(v1[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are a lot of issues with the code. start by doing something simpler, like displaying the items in a vector.

Answer (score 5):

You have *two* problems: The first about the error you have is because you *call* the function, but you should only provide a pointer to the function.

The second problem is harder to diagnose, but it's that the [range-for statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) gives you the *values* of the container and not the indexes. That means that `i` will be a `double` value, and you will get five of those values and each of them will be `0.0`.

To solve the last problem I suggest you do something like this instead

```
for (auto& v : v1)
{
    v = some_value;
}

std::cout << "Number of items whose value is less than 50: "
          << std::count_if(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), lessThan)
          << '\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

You must pass the predicate function itself to `count_if`, not the result of a call:

```
std::count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), lessThan);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the following

```
for (auto i : v1) {    //for each element in v1...(auto used to determine type)
    v1[i] = rand() % 100;    //generate random numbers
    cout << v1[i] << endl;
}

auto num = count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), lessThan );
```

Also you could use standard functional object std::less declared in header `<functional>`. For example

```
#include <functional>
//...

for (auto i : v1) {    //for each element in v1...(auto used to determine type)
    v1[i] = rand() % 100;    //generate random numbers
    cout << v1[i] << endl;
}

auto num = count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::bind2nd( std::less<double>(), 50.0 ) );
```

Or you could use a lambda expression

```
for (auto i : v1) {    //for each element in v1...(auto used to determine type)
    v1[i] = rand() % 100;    //generate random numbers
    cout << v1[i] << endl;
}

auto num = count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), []( double x ) { return x < 50.0; } );
```